Can the "Stateless" State Machine be made thread-safe with external locking?
I've understood from the start that the Stateless state machine is not thread safe.  But I don't need it to be as long as I have a way to fix it externally.  I was under the impression that if one simply put an external lock around every call to the StateMachine.Fire function, this could be resolved.
lock(_lock)
    MyMachine.Fire(Trigger.DoSomething);

Our application uses it this way for and works very well, but I occasionally (rarely) am told about errors that look (in my logs) like a state change that should not be possible given the triggers I've fired.  And it seems to happen mostly on slower machines, so it sounds like a race condition.
But I cannot reproduce it myself, so I am unable to determine if the problem is due to some other threading bug in my logic or due to the fact that this approach is fundamentally not adequate.
I've looked at the queuing logic in the source code and it seems like an external lock should work.
Do I need a new approach here?

Thank you for answering but it is not a database.  It is a state machine class.  There are no connections.  There is just my code, using it from several different threads.    I control every single place where the Fire method is called so I am able to lock it every time a trigger is fired.

That is true.   And I am locking in every single place I use it on every thread on which I use it.  It does not appear that the class itself is creating threads under the hood.  Not that I can see in the source code, anyway.    And I am not calling any of the Async firing methods.

Could the errors be occurring when an exception occurs?  I suspect you are returning from the middle of the method and not properly handling every state in the machine.  You probably have an incomplete state machine.

I catch and log every exception in the app (aside from things like user-cancellation scenarios which isn't the case here).   We don't have any catch clauses that simply silence the errors.  I think my job would be easier if the problem were an exception.    I am very motivated to track it down, but before I do that I want to make sure -- from someone who knows "Stateless" better than I -- that this approach I am using would not create a race condition.  (Again, taking as a given that I am truly locking every single call to Fire().  I have verified that part, at least.)

Can you please post the complete code that fails even if you can't replicate it?

I appreciate your desire to help but the state machine, along with the class which uses it is over 2000 lines of code.   Look:  I am not asking "what is the source of my bug?".  I am asking if my general approach to thread-safety (with the specific very popular github package "stateless") is sound.  That is all.  This is a question directed at people who are somewhat familiar with that package or who have done this themselves.  (I've also asked it on their page but that doesn't get a lot of traffic)

The general approach of using an external lock is sound. But things can get complicated if things like timers or asynchronous code are involved. Running something like CpuStres might help reproduce issues if it is due to timing.

Why do you think the issue is with the locking and not the state machine itself?

Because it is not designed to be used from multiple threads at the same time.  I'm trying to understand if applying external locking is a sound way to get around that restriction, given how stateless works internally.  In other words, as long as only one thread is in the fire function at a time is the integrity of the state machine always preserved?

Your (code) "lock" doesn't safeguard any "shared variables" that aren't handled with interlocked.

I'm not sure what you mean by "shared variables".  Do you mean member variables of the StateMachine class?.  Because  I should make clear that the only member function in the entire class that I call (after initialization) is the Fire function (and I lock for the duration of each call).  My reading of that function is that it returns only after the entire  trigger queue is emptied.  It does not appear to spin up any asynchronous operations under the hood.  But perhaps I am reading it wrong.
